# Compute $\lim_{|h|\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y+h)+f(y)|^p dy$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

> Suppose $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), 0<p<\infty$, and compute $\displaystyle \text{lim}_{|h|\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y+h)+f(y)|^p dy$

I have no idea from where to start since I do not know anything about $f$. Can anyone please give me a hint to start? (Please do not downvote this question, I cannot show research effort since I don't have any idea. I only need a hint, not a complete answer)

Comment: Try to get an answer when $f$ has compact support.

Comment: @Pp: But isn't it only works when $|h|\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Why do you want to compute that limit?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: This is just a problem I want to solve, not a part of another

Comment: @Mathi You are right. I didn't see the $\infty$.

Comment: Have you tried an example?

Answer (score 1):

If $p\in(1,\infty)$":

Show it for $g$ that is continuous and has compact support . Then use the fact that $C_c(\mathbb R^n)\subset L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ is a dense subset and use triangle inequality like that $\|f_h-f\|_p\leq \|f_h-g_h\|_p+\|g_h-g\|_p+\|g-f\|_p$.

$\|f_h-g_h\|_p,\|g-f\|_p<\epsilon$ for $\epsilon >0$.

Take $lim_{|h|}inf\|g_h-g\|_p\geq \|g(min(D_g)+g\|_p$ and $lim_{|h|}sup\|g_h-g\|_p\leq \|g(max(D_g)+g\|_p$

Comment: What is $g$ here?

Comment: @Mathi   You don't need to know the expression of $g$. Just that $lim_{|h|\to \infty} g(x+|h|)=g(max(D_g))$ , where $D_g=\overline {\{x\in \mathbb R^n:g(x)\neq 0\}}$

Comment: He's saying that $g$ is any function in $C_c(R^n)$, and you should first compute $\lim \int |g(y+h)+g(y)|^p$ for such $g$.

Answer (score 0):

For $1\le p\lt\infty$,
$$
\|f(x)\|_p=\lim_{M\to\infty}\left\|[|x|\le M]\,f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p\tag{1}
$$
where $[\cdots]$ are [Iverson brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Since
$$
\|f(x)\|_p^p=\left\|[|x|\le M]\,f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p^p+\left\|[|x|\gt M]\,f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p^p\tag{2}
$$
there is some $M_\epsilon$ so that for $M\ge M_\epsilon$
$$
\left\|[|x|\gt M]\,f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p\le\epsilon\tag{3}
$$
Now if $h\gt2M_\epsilon$, the supports of $[|x+h|\le M_\epsilon]f(x+h)$ and $[|x|\le M_\epsilon]f(x)$ are disjoint; therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\left\|[|x+h|\le M_\epsilon]f(x+h)+[|x|\le M_\epsilon]f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p^p\\
&=\left\|[|x+h|\le M_\epsilon]f(x+h)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p^p+\left\|[|x|\le M_\epsilon]f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p^p\\
&=2\left\|[|x|\le M_\epsilon]f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p^p\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
The triangle inequality, along with $(3)$, yields
$$
\begin{align}
2^{1/p}\left\|[|x|\le M_\epsilon]f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p
&\ge2^{1/p}\left(\|f\|_p-\left\|[|x|\gt M_\epsilon]f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p\right)\\
&\ge2^{1/p}\|f\|_p-2^{1/p}\epsilon\\[3pt]
&\ge2^{1/p}\|f\|_p-2\epsilon\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
The triangle inequality and $(3)$ say that
$$
\begin{align}
&\left\|[|x+h|\gt M_\epsilon]f(x+h)+[|x|\gt M_\epsilon]f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p\\
&\le\left\|[|x+h|\gt M_\epsilon]f(x+h)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p+\left\|[|x|\gt M_\epsilon]f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p\\
&=2\left\|[|x|\gt M_\epsilon]f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p\\
&\le2\epsilon\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
$(4)$, $(5)$, $(6)$, and the triangle inequality give that
$$
2^{1/p}\|f\|_p-4\epsilon\le\left\|f(x+h)+f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p\le2^{1/p}\|f\|_p+2\epsilon\tag{7}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{h\to\infty}\left\|f(x+h)+f(x)\vphantom{\sum}\right\|_p^p=2\|f\|_p^p\tag{8}
$$